# Probability of a random occurrence of Poisson process to be the first occurrence

Tags: probability, self-study, conditional-probability, poisson-process

It is given, that there is an occurrence of Poisson process (at time $t$) of intensity $\lambda$ within an interval $(0, T)$.

$t \in \{t_i\}; 0 < t_1 < t_2 < \cdots < t_n < T$

I need to calculate the probability it is the first occurrence within the interval.

$p = \Pr(t = t_1)$

I came up with the following solution:
$p = \int_0^T \frac{1}{T} e^{-\lambda t} dt = \frac{1 - e^{-\lambda T}}{\lambda T }$ since the distribution of a random occurrence within the interval is uniform.

However I do not feel very confident about the result, since I am not conditioning on the fact that there is at least one event within the interval.

When I do, I get $p_{cond} = \Pr(t = t_1 \mid n > 0) = \frac{p}{1 - e^{-\lambda T}} = \frac{1}{\lambda T}$.

Of course $\lim_{{\lambda T}\to 0} p_{cond} = \inf$, which is unacceptable.

Is my solution for $p$ correct despite of my doubt or do I need to condition it in a different way?

Comment: I don't understand the event whose (conditional) probability we are computing here. "There is an occurrence" does not specify a unique occurrence and thus it is unclear what "it" refers to in "it is the first occurrence". In other words, when there are multiple occurrences, how is "the one" we are considering selected?

Comment: @JuhoKokkala I have edited the question. The uniqueness of the occurrence is known by its time $t$. The problem is a subproblem of case in which $0 < t < \hat{T}$ and $T \le \hat{T}$. I know that $\Pr(t < T) = \frac{T}{\hat{T}}$, but I need to calculate $\Pr(t < T, \neg \exists_i t_i < t)$

Comment: Is $t$ a constant and we are conditioning on the event that one occurrence is at $t$?

Comment: @JuhoKokkala No, it is a random variable uniformly distributed within $(0, T)$

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the setting -- could you explain the full problem from where this arises?

Comment: @JuhoKokkala I may create a story behind: a website has decided to reward its first visitor in a particular period of time (from $0$ to $T$). What is a probability of winning the reward by a random user visiting the website once within a period from $0$ to $\hat{T}$? It is given that visits of users are arriving according to Poisson process of intensity $\lambda$.

Comment: I think the question is still ill-specified as it's unclear how the "random user" we are asking about is selected  (Poisson process arrivals are "unnamed" in a sense). Or is the idea that "I" go visit the site at a random period uniformly in $[0,T]$, other users arrive according to Poisson process, how likely I win the price? Or do we select the "user in question" with uniform distribution from the arrivals in the realization of the PP? (I guess these have different answers). Can you perhaps explain your actual "story behind" so one could decide how to best model the situation

Comment: I believe both cases describe the same situation (it is unknown, which arrival is "mine" - but "mine" arrival gives there is more than zero arrivals), but the latter is the case in the story.